# Python regex (or expression)

Tags: python, regex, optimization

I'm a beginner in Python, so I have doubts regarding code optimization. I hope you could advise me on that.
I'm solving next task:
There is text with one keyword in a row and its state, which can be different, for instance:

```
... task1 .... success....
... task1 .... failed...
... task1 .... inactive...
```

I have to track this state using keyword (also we have different tasks).

My code:

---

```
list_of_tasks = ['task1','task2','task3']
list_of_states = ['success','inactive','failed']

for task in list_of_tasks:
 regex='|'.join(('.*'+task+'.*'+state+'.*') for state in list_of_states)
 pattern = re.compile (regex)
 for line in text:
     m = re.match(pattern,str(line))
     if m:
          #operational logic
```

---

Can this regex be done in more efficient way?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is between the task and the state? Is it something like this: `"blah bla foo bar zoo task1 abc def 12345 success for cat dog mike"`, or is it like this `"    task1     success      "`

Answer (score 1):

You could also alternate through tasks, so your final regex look like

```
(task1|task2|task3).*(success|inactive|failed)
```

so you have **one** regex, and you can obtain the task name through `m.group(1)` and status through `m.group(2)`, but what is more important - if your file is actually just a bunch of lines in form

```
TASK STATUS
```

using regexes is completely redundant, you can simply split the string on the white char and retrieve the TASK and STATUS. Regexes are usefull only if it looks like

```
so I did research on TASK statistics 123 $ time 30s process& STATUS leads to a conclusion that blah
```